# How to prevent list from resetting?

Tags: python

Here the code looks if a letter is in a word and then returns a list with the guessed letter and the rest of the positions as underscores. My question is: is there a way to write this so the list does not reset every time? The goal would be for the loop to repeat until there are no more underscores in the list.

```
x = input('Wort')
i = 0

while i < len(x):
    y = input('Buchstabe:')
    listfirst = list(x)
    listsecond = []

    for letter in listfirst:    
        if letter == y: 
            listsecond.append(y)
        if letter != y: 
            listsecond.append(' _')
    
    print(listsecond)
    i = i+1
```

Comment: Probably a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not clear if listfirst or listsecond. But you should move the one you dont want to reset outside before the while begins

Answer (score 0):

Just put the list before the while loop.

```
x = input('Wort')
i = 0
listfirst = list(x)
listsecond = []

while i < len(x):
    y = input('Buchstabe:')
    for letter in listfirst:    
        if letter == y: 
            listsecond.append(y)
        if letter != y: 
            listsecond.append(' _')
    
    print(listsecond)
    i = i+1
```